# Four-lines script to make an immediate DB and document root zip backup

Tags: bash, server, wordpress

What do you think of my script to make an immediate DB and document root zip backup? Any flaw you might find. Please inform me of it:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
zip -r all_zipped-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip ${drt}/ -x "*/cache/*"
rm -rf  ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
```

It is important to me to have the backup in document root because of comfortability. It's a small server environment (with external automatic backups) and I think it'll be redundant to have a backup dir just for once-in-a-while immediate backups I do with that nice script above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bug?

It looks to me that the name of the zip file used in the first and the last command were intended to be the same, that is the `${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip` part:

> ```
> mysqldump ... | zip ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
> ...
> rm -rf  ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
> ```

They will only be the same if the `mysqldump` and `rm` commands run within the same second.

#### Don't repeat yourself

If a non-trivial command is expected to return the same value every time you run it, then extract it to a variable.
Not only to save unnecessary processing power,
but also to keep the non-trivial logic in one place,
so that it's easy to change if ever needed, in one place.

#### Double-quote command arguments

It's a good rule of thumb to double-quote command arguments when they contain variables,
to protect yourself from unintended word splitting and glob expansions.

#### Useless flags

In `rm -rf  ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip`,
since we're deleting a file, not a directory,
the `-r` flag is useless.
Avoid useless flags.

#### Alternative solution

I suggest to write like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date +\%F-\%T)

mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "${drt}/db-$date.zip"
zip -r "all_zipped-$date.zip" "${drt}"/ -x "*/cache/*"
rm -f "${drt}/db-$date.zip"
```

Comment: I didn't know how to handle that problem that problem of different timestamps in the files, for `mysqldump ... | zip ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip`VS `rm -rf  ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip`. Thanks for showing a way and for the rest of the answer. I am fully aware that `rf` is redundant when it's a file; It was a mistake. I thank you dearly. I would thumb up both your answers if I could. I miss 5 points.